# How to Move MS Word Footnotes Up Into Body Text

Tags: microsoft-word, mediawiki

I have a MS Word document with 100+ footnotes. I want to bring them into the text (where the superscript number currently is) spanned by a `<ref></ref>` tag so I can place the document on a wiki. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with a macro:

```
Sub AddFnTextInBodyOfDoc()
Dim f As Footnote
Dim r As Range

For Each f In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
Set r = f.Reference
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
r.InsertAfter "<ref>" & f.Range.Text & "</ref>"

Next f
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to delete each footnote reference number.

```
f.Reference.Delete
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).